# GetVirtualPathForArea returns wrong VirtualPath

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using Martijn Bolands [paging](http://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/2008/08/27/paging-with-aspnet-mvc/) and I have an issue with GetVirtualPathForArea method.

I have two pages: /Page1 and /Page2.

I've set a MapRoute for /Page1 and is accessed as /Page1Name

```
routes.MapRoute(
      "Page1 name", // Route name
       "Page1Name", // URL with parameters
       new { controller = "ContollerName", action = "ActionName" } // Parameter defaults
);
```

If I try to get the Vitrual Path from Page1Name page, it gives me the correct one.

But!! If I try to get the Virtual Path from page2, it gives me again the Page1Name.

I haven't set any Route for Page2 and If do this, then in Page1 I will get the VirtualPath of Page2.

**Call and Methods**

The call is through an HtmlHelper as follows

```
public static HtmlString Pager(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, int pageSize, int currentPage, int totalItemCount, string actionName, RouteValueDictionary valuesDictionary, string controllerName) {
        if (valuesDictionary == null) {
            valuesDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary();
        }
        if (actionName != null) {
            if (valuesDictionary.ContainsKey("action")) {
                throw new ArgumentException("The valuesDictionary already contains an action.", "actionName");
            }
            valuesDictionary.Add("action", actionName);
        }
        var pager = new Pager(htmlHelper.ViewContext, pageSize, currentPage, totalItemCount, valuesDictionary, null, controllerName);
        return pager.RenderHtml();
    }
```

This is from RenderHtml() method

It gets the viewContext from htmlHelper and this is the call to get the virtualPath

```
var pageLinkValueDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary(linkWithoutPageValuesDictionary) { { "page", pageNumber } };
var virtualPathForArea = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPathForArea(viewContext.RequestContext, pageLinkValueDictionary);
```

Is it a known issue? Have I set something in a wrong way?

Thanks and I'll appreciate any comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Response from microsoft:**

The behavior you’re mentioning here is actually “by design”, if a route URL (such as your first route: FirstPage) has no parameters, no defaults, and no constraints, the call to RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPathForArea() will match this route (when it gets to it as it tries to match the route one by one in the order they are added).
The general fix is to make one of those conditions false OR to use named routes.

You can read more about this in a blog post by Phil Haack here: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/11/21/named-routes-to-the-rescue.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Normally, a route that is registered could look like

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "ControllerName", action = "ActionName", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults,
);
```

meaning that doing a `Url.Action("Index","Home", new {id = 1})` would result in the url `/Home/Index/1`; the `{controller}/{action}/{id}` are placeholders for both interpreting a request (which controller, action and parameters to use) and generating url's.

If you look at your route defined (if it is the only one, or defined as the first) whatever you do with a `Url.Action(..)` it will always return `/Page1Name`

If you want to do as in the link provided

> Internally, the pager uses RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath() to render the url’s so the page url’s can be configured via routing to create nice looking url’s like for example `/Categories/Shoes/Page/1` instead of `/Paging/ViewByCategory?name=Shoes&page=1`.

Then you can register your route like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "PagingRoute", // Route name
    "Categories/{type}/Page/{page}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "PagingControllerName", 
          action = "Index", 
          type = UrlParameter.Optional, 
          page = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults,
);
```

and the matching method in the PagingController would be

```
public ActionResult Index(string type, int? page) { // do something}
```

---

#### update

If you are using Martijn Bolands pager, look at the second route he maps/registers:

```
routes.MapRoute("SimplePaging", "SimplePaging/{page}",  
    new { controller = "Paging", action = "Index", page = UrlParameter.Optional },
new[] { "MvcPaging.Demo.Controllers" });
```

then yours should be about the same (i.e. adding the UrlParameter page). But that would mean your url will always look like /Page1Name/[pagenumber]. If on the other hand Page1Name is your actual action, you should define your Route like:

```
routes.MapRoute("Page1 name", "{action}/{page}",    
    new { controller = "Paging", action = "Page1Name", page = UrlParameter.Optional },
);
```

Comment: The generated url is /Page1Name?page={number}. I can't set a route for something like this cause it contains '?'. Νevertheless I set the route Page1Name/Page/{page} and I it has the same behaviour.

Comment: Is that the only route you map? Or do you have more routes mapped? How does the method call look to get the virtual path?

Comment: I created a new mvc 3 project and I add two routes, one for Home controller with name HomePageName and one for Account controller with name AccountPageName. I add also a new view with name Index in account controller. If you try to get virtual path you will get wrong values [ var _virtualPath = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPathForArea(null, null); ]

Comment: This make the trick. But this is a hardCode fix, it is a little bit weird to return wrong values the GetVirtualPath() method. I expected to return the correct value. Anyway, thanks a lot for you help

Comment: It is not hardcoded, matter of the fact is that {action} makes it variable. @Url.Action("Page1Name", new {page = 3})  gives `/Page1Name/3` and @Url.Action("Page2Name", new {page = 4})  gives `/Page2Name/4`.   The `action = "Page1Name"` only defines the default action, so @Url.Action(new {page = 2}) would give `/Page1Name/2`.

Comment: I do agree with you. When I said hardCoded, I meant that I have a solution for make the project work, but the initial error where the GetVirtualPathForArea() returns different value still exists. I don't say only for the current project. I tried to build a new one to investigate the root of this issue and I saw that in an all new project, the behaviour was the same.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3196/discussion-between-major-byte-and-stroumfios)